# Angular and MySQL - Frontend Filtering vs Multiple Queries

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, optimization

I have a system of orders and am trying to figure out an efficient way to fetch and display the data. The orders are at different statuses, and I want to group them accordingly in their own tables.

I'm using AngularJS, and I was wondering what other experienced developers thought in regards to these options:

- Fetch all the orders with their status information, then filter the orders on the frontend.
- Run multiple MySQL queries (as many as necessary) and return the data already grouped from the backend (PHP).

The returned results are unlikely to ever be over 1000, but even that's pushing it. We won't retrieve completed orders. I'd be happy to provide more details if requested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm passing the website of my company for AngularJs. Before this, the entire website was in PHP. I had a page that filters about 400 items and each search was processing around 100ms. Now the "same" page in AngularJs is working with others itens, around +1000, and each search is processing around 200ms. The processing is a little bit bigger, but now I have much more flexibility and itens. With this experience, I think that is better you process the information on the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have multiple `orders` table?  If AngularJs is forcing that on you, then I would blame it.

Backend filtering is almost always better.

Multiple tables for the "same" kind of stuff is almost always bad.

Multiple queries is almost always worse than a single query.